# How to create encrypted data extensions using FuelSDK C#?

Tags: fuel-sdk, c#, dataextensions

My application requirements need a set of encrypted data extensions replicated across multiple folders.  I've managed to get data extension creation working but I haven't found any ways to specify fields as encrypted.  Is this something that just doesn't exist?

Or maybe is it possible to manually create an encrypted data extension and just copy it?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the sample FuelSDK C# application available on [Github](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp). It does not do encryption by itself but it's easy to change the source code to do encryption/ decryption in C#. Something along these lines (may vary based on encryption technique you want to use)

E.g.

Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

There are [encryption methods](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/encryption/Base64Encode.html) available in AmpScript as well but for a C# application, it might be the simplest solution to use custom methods such as above.

Comment: So you're saying I should use these methods to encryp the data when feeding it into the data extension via FuelSDK? And then in the content templates, use the encryption functions in ampscript to unencrypt them?